# How to convert a PowerShell script for use in a .bat

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get this PowerShell command script to run in a batch file and just cannot seem to get it to work. Thank you in advance. It works fine in PowerShell, I just need it to work in a bat.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('APPNAME')
Sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}');
```

Comment: Why not call the ps1 in your batch? And first of all why use a batch when Powershell can do it too?

Comment: You can run this in a batch file: `powershell -command "$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;$wshell.AppActivate('Untitled - Notepad');Sleep 1;$wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}');"`

Comment: Simpler: `powershell $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; $wshell.AppActivate('Untitled - Notepad'); Sleep 1; $wshell.SendKeys('{ENTER}')` See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672784/convert-a-small-ps-script-into-a-long-line-in-a-batch-file)

Comment: It runs and returns false and does not switch to the open app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shortest way possible while accounting for things that happen like logos, profiles, and policies getting in the way:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -NoLogo -Command "$wsh=New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;$wsh.AppActivate('Appname');Start-Sleep 1000;$wsh.SendKeys('{ENTER}')"
```

As an aside, semicolons are unnecessary in PowerShell scripts except to separate statements on the same line.

Comment: So I am getting the following error.

New-Object : Cannot find type [wscript.shell]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: @TrevorTeape looks like it's searching for an assembly rather than com object for some reason.  I've updated my answer explicitly naming the com

Comment: Now it runs, but returns false instead of switching to the open app by name. I appreciate all your help so far by the way.

Comment: @TrevorTeape If that's the case, there is a problem in your vb example then.

Comment: That's very weird because it will do what I need as a powershell script without errors. I may just have to make it a ps1 and find a work around for how to get the ps1 to open in a fashion I need.

Comment: @TrevorTeape I'd suggest writing a `.cmd` or `.bat` wrapper for the PS script.  `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "path\to\file.ps1"`

Comment: I found out that I need to include the Get-Process from powershell in the bat for it to not return false, I am not sure how to include that in the format cmd/bat needs.