# PowerShell in bat (multiline code as one line)

Tags: powershell, batch-file

There is a working batch file with PowerShell code in one line:

```
powershell -Command "& {$cont = wget http://САЙТ.info/; $cont = $cont.Content; $FilePath = 'contentFronHtml.txt' -f $env:SystemDrive; $cont | Out-File -FilePath $FilePath -Append -Width 200;}"
```

I want to break the PowerShell code to get something like:

```
SET LONG_COMMAND="$cont = wget http://САЙТ.info/;"
"$cont = $cont.Content;"
"$FilePath = 'contentFronHtml.txt' -f $env:SystemDrive;$cont | Out-File -
FilePath; $FilePath -Append -Width 200;"
powershell -Command "& {LONG_COMMAND}"
```

How do I connect strings of PowerShell code?

Comment: String concatenation is done  using + and for escape sequence you need to use baktick.

Comment: You can encode your script to base64 since powershell can run a base64 encoded script from the command prompt.

Comment: I tried it did not work.
you can use a concrete example

Comment: base64 encode your script! That's a horrible idea, as an example as it changes `powershell -Command 'echo "Hello World"'` into `powershell.exe -encodedCommand ZQBjAGgAbwAgACIASABlAGwAbABvACAAVwBvAHIAbABkACIA` --
 which is totally unreadable by a human!

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672784/convert-a-small-ps-script-into-a-long-line-in-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would expect to do this sort of thing:

```
PowerShell -Command "first line up to the end of a command;"^
 "next line up to the end of a command;"^
 "another line up to the end of a command;"^
 "last line"
```

You could also try this idea too:

```
Set "MyCmnd=first line up to the end of a command;"
Set "MyCmnd=%MyCmnd% next line up to the end of a command;"
Set "MyCmnd=%MyCmnd% another line up to the end of a command;"
Set "MyCmnd=%MyCmnd% last line"
Echo %MyCmnd%
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save your PowerShell code as a .ps1 file and then run it from the command line:

```
powershell -File "C:\folder\test.ps1"
```

Then to break long commands up over multiple lines, follow the answer from: *[How to enter a multi-line command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235850/how-to-enter-a-multi-line-command)*

This means you're separating your PowerShell code from your batch code, and no longer have inline PowerShell code within a batch file which can get hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
echo>%temp%\file.ps1 SET LONG_COMMAND="$cont = wget http://САЙТ.info/;"
echo>>%temp%\file.ps1 "$cont = $cont.Content;"
echo>>%temp%\file.ps1 "$FilePath = 'contentFronHtml.txt' -f
echo>>%temp%\file.ps1 $env:SystemDrive;$cont ^| Out-File -
echo>>%temp%\file.ps1 FilePath; $FilePath -Append -Width 200;"
echo>>%temp%\file.ps1 powershell -Command "& {LONG_COMMAND}"

powershell %temp%\file.ps1
```