# How do I create a bat file that executes powershell script without an external ps1 file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

There is an existing question of how to run a ps1 file when you double click found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137146/is-there-any-way-to-make-powershell-script-work-by-double-clicking-ps1-file). However I want to know if there is a solution that does not require 2 separate files.

Comment: In answer to your specific question, yes there is.

Comment: The batch file can run powershell and give it a scriptblock of code to execute.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate question.  Several questions about this already.

Comment: You may review a simple method to _embed_ PS code into a Batch file at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672784/convert-a-small-ps-script-into-a-long-line-in-a-batch-file).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a PowerShell script within a Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609985/how-to-run-a-powershell-script-within-a-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is to embed the Powershell script into a .bat file with a combination of echos and comments:

```
echo `
REM | Out-Null <#
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((Get-Content \"%~f0\") -join \"`n\") | Out-Null"
goto :eof
#>

(powershell script here)

<#
:eof
::#>
```

This results in some artifacts in the console output but the script is successfully run embedded in a bat file. This works without errors because "echo" is both a Windows Command Line command as well as a Powershell command.

EDIT:
Here I am years later with an improved version:

```
@powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$_=((Get-Content \"%~f0\") -join \"`n\");iex $_.Substring($_.IndexOf(\"goto :\"+\"EOF\")+9)"
@goto :EOF

(powershell script here)
```

Improvements:

- Only requires a 2 line file header (I didn't know about `:EOF`)
- No console output unless you do so from the script
- Compatible with `Write-Output` due to only passing the actual script content to powershell.exe

Comment: An enhancement: instead `@goto :EOF`, I'm using `exit %ERRORLEVEL%` and `$_.IndexOf('exit' + ' ')` to allow propagation of exit code.