# powershell command into batch - it doesn't work

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I would like to run a powershell command with batch. My powershell command:

```
gc 'C:\Users\Test\Test-01\source.csv' | %{
    $cols = $_.split(";")
    1..$cols[-2]| %{
        "$($cols[0..9] -join ';');$($cols[(9+$_)] -join ';');$($cols[(24+$_)] -join ';');;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$($cols[-2]);"
    }
} | sc "C:\Users\Test\Test-01\target.csv"
```

My batch command:

```
powershell -Executionpolicy ByPass gc 'C:\Users\Test\Test-01\source.csv' | %{
        $cols = $_.split(";")
        1..$cols[-2]| %{
            "$($cols[0..9] -join ';');$($cols[(9+$_)] -join ';');$($cols[(24+$_)] -join ';');;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$($cols[-2]);"
        }
    } | sc "C:\Users\Test\Test-01\target.csv"
```

It doesn't work. But why? Can someone say why?

Comment: it does not work since that is not how one calls a PoSh script from a BAT file. [*grin*] please, read the docs on how to use `powershell.exe` when called from BAT or CMD files [or other programs].

Comment: You can begin by getting rid of the unneeded `-Executionpolicy ByPass` part.

Comment: If I remove it, it won't work ... is something missing?

Comment: Yes, you cannot expect a multiline powershell command to work like that. `-Executionpolicy` is for use when running powershell scripts, _(generally `*.ps1`)_. You're not running a powershell script, you're running a powershell command.

Comment: Why don't you use import-csv and export-csv?

Answer (score 1):

To embedd PowerShell code into a .BATch file you just need to pay attention to a few details:

- Eliminate all `-ExecutionPolicy` and `-Command` stuff. Just write pure powershell code after `powershell` command.
- Terminate each line with caret: `^`
- Terminate each *complete powershell command* with semicolon: `;`
- Escape each quote with a backslash: `\"like this\"` *or* change they by apostrophe: `'like this'`

And these modifications are required because Batch file special characters:

- Duplicate percent signs: `%%`
- Escape these characters: `| > < &` with caret, like this: `^| ^> ^< ^&`

In your case this is the final, working code:

```
powershell  ^
gc 'C:\Users\Test\Test-01\source.csv' ^| %%{  ^
    $cols = $_.split(\";\");  ^
    1..$cols[-2]^| %%{  ^
        \"$($cols[0..9] -join ';');$($cols[(9+$_)] -join ';');$($cols[(24+$_)] -join ';');;;;;;;;;;;;;;;$($cols[-2]);\"  ^
    }  ^
} ^| sc \"C:\Users\Test\Test-01\target.csv\"
```

You may also review [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672784/convert-a-small-ps-script-into-a-long-line-in-a-batch-file).